# Exception when adding control to custom cell

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin and a custom table cell (derived from UITableViewCell), this works fine:

```
[Register("MyCell")]
public class MyCell: UITableViewCell
{
    private UILabel myLabel;

    public MyCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        myLabel= new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16),
            Text = "My Label",
            BackgroundColor =  UIColor.Cyan
        };

        ContentView.Add(myLabel);
    }
}
```

However, if I derive from `MvxTableViewCell` instead (because I ultimately want my cell to be data bound) I have an exception thrown on the `ContentView.Add(myLabel)` line:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

This is before any attempt to bind any data.

Any ideas what is going on? What's the right way to create a custom cell in code using Mvx? I've had custom cells work with Mvx using `.xib` files, but they seem to be a little clunky to use when trying to work with visual studio on the PC and Xamarin studio on the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is exactly as above except with `UITableViewCell` replaced with `MvxTableViewCell` and you haven't done any binding externally to change this, then there's nothing in MvxTableViewCell that should cause this - from [MvxTableViewCell.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewCell.cs) - it's just a simple layer on top of `UITableViewCell`

In my opinion, your best bet is to collect a bit more basic information:

- is there an inner exception of that `TargetInvocationException`? If so, where is that inner exception thrown?
- where is the reflection itself happening here?

If you can work that out, then you might have more chance in debugging and solving the problem

Comment: Thanks, as always, for your response Stuart. I don't see any inner exception offered up in Visual Studio, so I really don't know what's happening here. I'm going to give `xib`'s another try and see if I can get them to behave. There are a whole lot of complications with going between the Mac and the PC which seems to mess up my project.

Comment: Sorry. Without a stack trace, an inner exception or a repro, then not sure I can help debug it - it could be anything :/